# Use standard android animation for changing screens in single activity Compose app?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I notice that most **android apps** have the **same animation** when **changing screens**, like this:

[image]

I guess it automatically occurs when changing Activities but in `Jetpack Compose` it is best practice to **only use one Activity** for the whole application.

How can I still use **this exact animation** in an `animatedNavHost` for example?

Comment: You can give different animation for different screens when you navigate them. And I don't think most of the apps have the same animation.

Comment: @c-an I know that. I want to avoid writing own animations for my navHost as they tend not to be smooth for complex screens. When creating an App with multiple Activities in Android Studio and run it above Animation is the default when starting or leaving an Activity. I cannot find a way to use this exact Animation somewhere else though.

Comment: I will be using activities instead of compose navigation as long as the system transition isn't used by compose, and Google asking us to move away from a standard transition animation system is actively making android feel less coherent imo